# htaccess rewriting rule does not work for homepage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP website. I want to convert the PHP page names into SEO friendly page names.
So, first of all I want to convert the homepage, I want to remove the mention of "index". As its a multilanguage site, there are english and french versions of the homepage.

I want:

```
www.abc.com/index.php?lang=fr
```

to become

```
www.abc.com/fr/
```

However, after that, I want other pages to keep their name, for example:
I want:

```
www.abc.com/links.php?lang=fr
```

to become

```
www.abc.com/fr/links/
```

I also want the url to work without the trailing slash.
So this:

```
www.abc.com/fr/links
```

should give the same page as this:

```
www.abc.com/fr/links/
```

and this:

```
www.abc.com/fr
```

should give the same page as this:

```
www.abc.com/fr/
```

The contents of my htaccess file so far is below.
It enables me to change the links page correctly, however, I can't figure out how to do the index page in the way I describe above (plus it is possible that the code below is very bad, as I am only a starter on htaccess so don't hold back on the criticism, I'm mainly advancing by guesswork so far...)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)/index(/*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/links(/*)$ links.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]` something like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would match allowed languages explicitly to have more control about what URLs are matched.

If you had "fr" and "en" allowed, it should work with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /fr/links and /fr/links/ to links.php?lang=fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.+)(/?)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L]

# Rewrite /fr and /fr/ to index.php?lang=fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)(/?)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

While this should work, I would rather go a different route in the actual implementation. I would redirect all requests to a single index.php file and do the route matching there, which keeps your .htaccess clean and simple:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite everything not existing to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And in index.php parse language and page and do your includes appropriately.

Comment: I used the first solution you suggested for now. However, I admit I don't understand how it works, because www.abc.com/en or www.abc.com/en/ yields the index page alright, fair enough, but what in your rewrite rule enables www.abc.com to display the index page ?

Comment: That is not included, I did not see it in the question. But now I re-read and assume you also want to have redirects for all old URL? And which language should be chosen if someone enters www.abc.com?